# Reverse for 'ipads_by_school' with keyword arguments '{'school_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<school_id>[^/]+)$'] - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Django/Python.

The line of code from my index.html that generates the NoReverseMatch error in the title is this.

```
<a href="{% url 'ipads_by_school' school_id=LES %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1" >LES</a>
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:school_id>', views.ipads_by_school, name='ipads_by_school')
]
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Ipad

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'ipads/index.html')

def ipads_by_school(request, school_id):
    school_ipads = Ipad.objects.filter(school_id__icontains=school_id)

    context = {
        'school_ipads': school_ipads
    }

    return render(request, 'ipads/ipads_by_school.html', context)
```

Comment: try `school_id='LES'`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!  I can't believe it was something as simple as that.